# Termination proof and complexity of a algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, termination

I have written the following algorithm

- $select(\Pi)$ select the first elements from $\Pi$. When there are no element in $\Pi$, it return $\emptyset$. Always terminates .Worst case complexity $O(1)$
- $processing(e)$ function take a element $e$ as input and process it. And based on the processing it either output element $r$ or $\emptyset$. Always terminates. Complexity not known.
- $update(r,\Pi,\Delta)$ function take $r,\Pi,\Delta$ as input and update criteria in the function. And based new criteria, it transfer already processing element from $\Delta$ to $\Pi$. Always terminates. Worst case complexity $O(sizeof(\Pi+\Delta))$

$\textbf{Input} - \textbf{a set of elements $\Pi$}$

$\textbf{Output} - \textbf{a set of elements $C$}$

$C$=$\emptyset$;

$\Delta$=$\emptyset$;

$e$=$select(\Pi)$;

$\textbf{While}$($e \not=\emptyset$){

$\hspace{10mm}r$=$processing(e)$;

$\hspace{10mm}\textbf{if}$($r \not=\emptyset$){

$\hspace{20mm} C$=$C\cup r$;

$\hspace{20mm} \Pi$=$\Pi-e$;

$\hspace{20mm} \Pi,\Delta$=$update(r,\Pi,\Delta)$;

$\hspace{10mm}\}\textbf{else}${

$\hspace{20mm} \Pi$=$\Pi-e$;

$\hspace{20mm} \Delta$=$\Delta\cup e$;

$\hspace{10mm}$}

$\hspace{10mm}e$=$select(\Pi)$;

}

$\textbf{return}$ $C$;

Proof Sketch ----
The termination condition of the algorithm - when $\Pi$ is $\emptyset$.
Each iteration of the loop involves a $processing$ call which always terminates. Because $processing$ does not return any results for 10 seconds, then algorithm terminates the $processing$ call and return $\emptyset$.  We can say that the algorithm always terminates since the size of $\Pi$ and $\Delta$ move in a monotone way up and down respectively, and one always moves. Thus, eventually $\Pi$ become empty and the algorithm terminates.

Can anyone please suggest to me how I can formally complete the proof?

Can anyone please suggest how we can compute the worst case complexity as we do not know the complexity of the $processing$ function? How we can use Oracle for $processing$ function in that process?

Comment: Also, perhaps it is just obvious from the question text, but *what exactly it is you are trying to prove?* That *all* your claims preceding the algorithm (i.e., its specification) are correct? Or just what is stated in the question's title?

Comment: I need a suggestion whether my Proof Sketch is correct for this algorithm. If you yes how I can construct the proof? Is any other information we need to consider to complete the proof.

Comment: I am updating question by removing the image. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I think you have not stated enough hypotheses to guarantee termination. It could be the case that `processing` always returns $\emptyset$, and in that case we get stuck into an infinite loop.

Comment: Extremely sorry. There is a typo I have updated the algorithm.